# Extract contents of a file using ContentHandler

Tags: java, string, file, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract the contents of a txt file using ContentHandler, the below is my code and the contents of my file is

```
Sample content Sample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample contentSample
```

The below code is not showing the extracted contents, what am I missing here?

```
class Test { 
private OutputStream outputstream;
private ParseContext context;
private Detector detector;
private Parser parser;
private Metadata metadata;
private String extractedText;

public Test() {
    context = new ParseContext();
    detector = new DefaultDetector();
    parser = new AutoDetectParser(detector);
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    metadata = new Metadata();
}

public void process(String filename) throws Exception {
    URL url;
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.isFile()) {
        url = file.toURI().toURL();
    } else {
        url = new URL(filename);
    }
    InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(url, metadata);
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(outputstream);
    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context); 
    input.close();
}

public void getString() {
    //Get the text into a String object
    extractedText = outputstream.toString();
    //Do whatever you want with this String object.
    System.out.println("extracted text "+extractedText);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    if (args.length == 1) {
        Test textExtractor = new Test();
        textExtractor.process("D:\\docs\\sample.txt");
        textExtractor.getString();
    } else { 
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you added the tika-parsers depedency in addition to tika-core ?If not added the required dependency and try again.

Comment: Did you try [following the instructions on the Apache Tika Troubleshooting page](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add apache tika-parsers dependency in addition to apache tika-core.